# How should I name my message file?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a cmake dependency that has all my messages, however the following error happens:

```
rosidl_adapter.parser.InvalidResourceName: 'testMsg' is an invalid message
name.  It should have the pattern '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*$'
```

Looks like that the name of my message file is incorrect, but I do not understand what ^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*$' means.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389288/how-should-i-name-my-message-file?/) by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer,

```
^[A-Z]
```

Means upper case letter, and

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]
```

Means upper case letter followed by lower case letters or numbers. Thus, my message name was wrong because I was using

```
'testMsg'
```

Which does not starts with a capitol letter. This problem was solved just by writing:

```
'TestMsg'
```

---

Originally posted by [JollyRogers](https://answers.ros.org/users/33294/jollyrogers/) with karma: 58 on 2021-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1